# Running a java code that generates a csv file as Jenkins job

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have some doubts about this, first I want to run my java code in a Jenkins pipeline, and my java needs to get 2 folders as arguments from the Jenkins running environment (linux) and then, my java code will do certain comparisons and generate a csv file.
how to run the java code in my Jenkins job? is it simply to get my cloned java code and run mvn clean compile? and how I can send the arguments from jenkins running environment to the java code? and finally how can I let my csv file appear on my Jenkins job dashboard?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Except the last requirement, is seems possible doing so. At last one I'm not sure this is a possible.

Comment: I have run my code locally an d all working fine and generating a csv file but locally (ex: D:/Documents/myGeneratedcsvFile.csv ) , now I want to automate my code on Jenkins and to sent my code as arguments 2 folder names and then generate the csv file in the Jenkins job

Comment: So do you need a pipeline script or something else? Have you read my previous comment complete?

Comment: yes a pipeline script. and yes I read your comment complete, and I explained what I have tried so far, hope it's clear

Comment: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/ is a documentation for creating a pipeline. You will need the command `sh` for executing your java program with parameters.